# error: no matching constructor for initialization of ... and mexFunction

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to wrap a C++ code in matlab using mex interface. However, when following the existing examples about how to construct the mexFunction, I encountred some issues. One of them when I want to call the second constructor of my class (no default one) then I got the following error when I compile

> C___class_interface/RBergomiST.cpp:300:30: error: no
>   matching constructor for initialization of 'RBergomiST'
>           RBergomiST_instance=RBergomiST(x,  HIn, e, r,t, k,  NIn,  MIn);
>                                ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The code I am using is the following. Any help please?

```
#include "class_handle.hpp"
#include "RBergomiST.h"
#include "mex.h"
RBergomiST::RBergomiST() {
  N = 0;
  M = 0;
  nDFT = 0;
  par = ParamTot();
  xC = new fftw_complex[0];
  xHat = new fftw_complex[0];
  yC = new fftw_complex[0];
  yHat = new fftw_complex[0];
  zC = new fftw_complex[0];
  zHat = new fftw_complex[0];
 }

RBergomiST::RBergomiST(double x, Vector HIn, Vector e, Vector r, Vector t,
  Vector k, int NIn, long MIn){

  N = NIn;
  nDFT = 2 * N - 1;
  M = MIn;
  par = ParamTot(HIn, e, r, t, k, x);
  xC = new fftw_complex[nDFT];
  xHat = new fftw_complex[nDFT];
  yC = new fftw_complex[nDFT];
  yHat = new fftw_complex[nDFT];
  zC = new fftw_complex[nDFT];
  zHat = new fftw_complex[nDFT];
  fPlanX = fftw_plan_dft_1d(nDFT, xC, xHat, FFTW_FORWARD,
        FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fPlanY = fftw_plan_dft_1d(nDFT, yC, yHat, FFTW_FORWARD,
        FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fPlanZ = fftw_plan_dft_1d(nDFT, zHat, zC, FFTW_BACKWARD,
        FFTW_ESTIMATE);
      }
RBergomiST::~RBergomiST() {
  delete[] xC;
  delete[] xHat;
  delete[] yC;
  delete[] yHat;
  delete[] zC;
  delete[] zHat;
  }  
void RBergomiST::updateWtilde(Vector& Wtilde, const Vector& W1, const 
     Vector& W1perp, double H) {
  Vector Gamma(N);
  getGamma(Gamma, H);
  double s2H = sqrt(2.0 * H);
  double rhoH = s2H / (H + 0.5);
  Vector W1hat = linearComb(rhoH / s2H, W1, sqrt(1.0 - rhoH * rhoH) / 
          s2H,W1perp);
  Vector Y2(N); // see R code
  // Convolve W1 and Gamma
  // Copy W1 and Gamma to complex arrays
  copyToComplex(W1, xC);
  copyToComplex(Gamma, yC);
  // DFT both
  fftw_execute(fPlanX); // DFT saved in xHat[0]
  fftw_execute(fPlanY); // DFT saved in yHat[0]
  // multiply xHat and yHat and save in zHat
  complexMult(xHat, yHat, zHat);
  // inverse DFT zHat
  fftw_execute(fPlanZ);
  // read out the real part, re-scale by 1/nDFT
  copyToReal(Y2, zC);
  scaleVector(Y2, 1.0 / nDFT);
  // Wtilde = (Y2 + W1hat) * sqrt(2*H) * dt^H ??
  Wtilde = linearComb(sqrt(2.0 * H) * pow(1.0 / N, H), Y2,
        sqrt(2.0 * H) * pow(1.0 / N, H), W1hat);
       }
void RBergomiST::scaleWtilde(Vector& WtildeScaled, const Vector& 
      Wtilde,double T, double H) const {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
       WtildeScaled[i] = pow(T, H) * Wtilde[i];
      }
void RBergomiST::scaleZ(Vector& ZScaled, const Vector& Z, double 
          sdt) const {
     for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      ZScaled[i] = sdt * Z[i];
      }
void RBergomiST::updateV(Vector& v, const Vector& WtildeScaled, 
           double h, double e, double dt) const {
       v[0] = par.xi();
       for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
            v[i] = par.xi() * exp(
            e * WtildeScaled[i - 1] - 0.5 * e * e
                    * pow((i - 1) * dt, 2 * h));
      }
void RBergomiST::getGamma(Vector& Gamma, double H) const {
   double alpha = H - 0.5;
   Gamma[0] = 0.0;
   for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
           Gamma[i] = (pow(i + 1.0, alpha + 1.0) - pow(i, alpha + 
               1.0)) / (alpha+ 1.0);
   }
void RBergomiST::copyToComplex(const Vector& x, fftw_complex* xc) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
            xc[i][0] = x[i]; // real part
            xc[i][1] = 0.0; // imaginary part
        }
        // fill up with 0es
        for (size_t i = x.size(); i < nDFT; ++i) {
            xc[i][0] = 0.0; // real part
            xc[i][1] = 0.0; // imaginary part
        }
    }
void RBergomiST::copyToReal(Vector& x, const fftw_complex* xc) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
            x[i] = xc[i][0]; // real part
     }
void RBergomiST::complexMult(const fftw_complex* x, const fftw_complex* 
          y,    fftw_complex* z) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nDFT; ++i)
            fftw_c_mult(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
     }
void RBergomiST::fftw_c_mult(const fftw_complex a, const fftw_complex 
        b,  fftw_complex c) {
        c[0] = a[0] * b[0] - a[1] * b[1];
        c[1] = a[0] * b[1] + a[1] * b[0];
      }
long RBergomiST::getM() const {
    return M;
    }
void RBergomiST::setM(long m) {
        M = m;
      }
int RBergomiST::getN() const {
     return N;
  }
void RBergomiST::setN(int n) {
        N = n;
  }
double RBergomiST::getXi() const {
return par.xi();
 }
double RBergomiST::intVdt(const Vector & v, double dt) const
 {
        return dt * std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
  }
double RBergomiST::intRootVdW(const Vector & v, const Vector & W1, double 
    sdt) const
 {
        double IsvdW = 0.0;
        for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
            IsvdW += sqrt(v[i]) * sdt * W1[i];
         return IsvdW;
  }
double RBergomiST::updatePayoff(long i, Vector& Wtilde,
    Vector& WtildeScaled, const Vector& W1, const Vector& W1perp, 
            Vector& v){
  double dt = par.T(i) / N;
  double sdt = sqrt(dt);
  bool update = par.HTrigger(i);
  if (update)
     updateWtilde(Wtilde, W1, W1perp, par.H(i));
  update = update || par.TTrigger(i);
  if (update) {
            scaleWtilde(WtildeScaled, Wtilde, par.T(i), par.H(i));
  }

  update = update || par.etaTrigger(i);
  if (update)
    updateV(v, WtildeScaled, par.H(i), par.eta(i), dt);

  double Ivdt = intVdt(v, dt);
  double IsvdW = intRootVdW(v, W1, sdt);
  double BS_vol = sqrt((1.0 - par.rho(i)*par.rho(i)) * Ivdt); 
  double BS_spot = exp( - 0.5 * par.rho(i)*par.rho(i) * Ivdt + 
      par.rho(i) * IsvdW );
  return BS_call_price(BS_spot, par.K(i), 1.0, BS_vol);
       }
double RBergomiST::ComputePayoffRT_single(const Vector & W1, const Vector 
                  & W1perp){
          Vector Wtilde(N);
          Vector WtildeScaled(N); // Wtilde scaled according to time
          Vector v(N);
          double payoff = updatePayoff(0, Wtilde, WtildeScaled, W1, 
              W1perp, v);
              return payoff;
   }
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray 
                   *prhs[]){

     double x; 
     x= mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
     double *HIn; 
     HIn= mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
     double *e; 
     e= mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
     double *r; 
     r= mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
     double *t;
     t= mxGetPr(prhs[4]);
     double *k;
     k= mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
     int NIn;
     NIn= mxGetN(prhs[6]);
     long MIn;
     MIn= mxGetN(prhs[7]);      
     char cmd[64];
 if (nrhs < 1 || mxGetString(prhs[0], cmd, sizeof(cmd)))
     mexErrMsgTxt("First input should be a command string less 
             than 64 characters long.");
     if (!strcmp("new", cmd)) {
             if (nlhs != 1)
                 mexErrMsgTxt("New: One output expected.");

     plhs[0] = convertPtr2Mat<RBergomiST>(new RBergomiST);
     return;
     }
     if (nrhs < 2)
            mexErrMsgTxt("Second input should be a class instance 
                    handle.");
     if (!strcmp("delete", cmd)) {
             destroyObject<RBergomiST>(prhs[1]);
     if (nlhs != 0 || nrhs != 2)
           mexWarnMsgTxt("Delete: Unexpected arguments ignored.");
     return;
     }

     RBergomiST* RBergomiST_instance = convertMat2Ptr<RBergomiST> 
                 (prhs[1]);
     if(nrhs==8) {
           RBergomiST_instance=convertMat2Ptr<RBergomiST>(RBergomiST(x,  HIn, 
                             e, r,t, k,  NIn,  MIn));      
           return;
                 }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`RBergomiST_instance` is a pointer to a `RBergomiST` object. On the line of the error you're trying to assign an object to this pointer.

It looks like you forgot to call the `convertMat2Ptr` function on this line, and it should instead be:
`RBergomiST_instance=convertMat2Ptr<RBergomiST>(RBergomiST(x,  HIn, e, r,t, k,  NIn,  MIn));`

Comment: Many thanks. You are right, but even when fixing this I got  the same error when compiling!

Comment: Right, looking at the error, the actual issue is with the constructor itself. you declare you ctor as `RBergomiST(double x, Vector HIn, Vector e, Vector r, Vector t, Vector k, int NIn, long MIn)` but on the line of the error you are using variables of type `double*` instead of type `Vector` for `HIn`, `e`, `r`, `t,` and `k`.

Comment: Well this may be the reason, but I am not sure. In fact, I was not able to define Vector type with mex interface so I used pointers instead!!

Comment: And how exactly do you expect a `double*` type to be converted implicitly to a `Vector` type? This isn't possible and the cause of your error. You either need to change the constructor, or change the call to it.